# Get numerical value of integer in binary file header

Tags: linux, command-line

I'd like to check whether the header of a file written in [STL format](http://www.ennex.com/~fabbers/StL.asp) is formed correctly.

The header starts with an 80-byte string, and after that is a 4-byte unsigned integer; this integer is the number whose value I want to check.

I tried to display the first 84 bytes like this:

```
head -c 84 test_above2GB_fails.stl
```

but this gives me:

```
solid                                                                           (\?
```

So this command works fine for the string (`solid` is ok) but the integer is interpreted as characters `(\?`.

How can I display the numerical value of that integer? (In decimal or hex or anything else numerical.)

Comment: Please provide a line of the file as an example.

Comment: It looks like you need another command, for example `od`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this to look at that integer after 80 bytes of data

```
cat test_above2GB_fails.stl | dd ibs=1 skip=80 2>/dev/null | od -tu4
```

`dd`is used to skip first 80 bytes. `od -td4` means to format input as 4-bytes unsigned decimal. You can use `od -tx1` to view in hex mode

or without using `cat` and read only 4 bytes from 80 to 84

```
dd if=test_above2GB_fails.stl ibs=1 skip=80 count=4 2>/dev/null | od -tu4
```

Comment: What is `2>/dev/null` for? One issue with this command is that, though it skips the first 80 bytes, it displays the next 2 billion, so the relevant bit of info gets drowned out. How would I stop output after that relevant integer?

Comment: `dd` print some annoying summary information after execution to stderr on my ubuntu14.04, so i add that to suppress it. You can eliminate it if it's not a issue on you machine. I have updated the answer with a better solution which has no need to cat the file and read only 4 bytes you want to check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `od` by itself:

```
od -An -tu4 -j 80 -N 0x4 --endian=little test_above2GB_fails.stl
```